# ArrayList doesn't show up on Spinner

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner, android-xml, android-adapter

I was trying to create a spinner which display a list of data from array list.

When I clicked on the dropdown it displays the list, but when I clicked on an item inside the dropdown list it doesn't show up the value on the spinner.

Am I missing something here?

**Note:** Yesterday I have tried to check using Log.d() and System.out.println, itemOnSelected() doesn't but today it works fine. Maybe I rebuilding the project or I have changed something in the code but the value on the spinner still doesn't show up after I clicked on the item inside the spinner.

```
Spinner spnSubjectIDInfo;
ArrayList<String> subjectList;
ArrayAdapter<String> adpSubj;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    subjectList = new ArrayList<String>();
    subjectList .add("John");
    subjectList .add("Maxi");
    subjectList .add("Jeni");

    spnSubjectIDInfo = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spnSubjectIDInfo);
    adpSubj = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, subjectList);
    adpSubj.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spnSubjectIDInfo.setAdapter(adpSubj);

    spnSubjectIDInfo.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(this, parent.getItemAtPosition(position)+ " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
```

**XML**

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spnSubjectIDInfo"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: you can try to changing "Toast.makeText(this.." to  "Toast.makeText(getBaseContext()"

Comment: 'getItemAtPosition' method returns an Object. You need to call the 'toString()' method to get the string representation of that said object.

Comment: post your full code

Comment: because you are trying to set 2 times spinner(drop down)     view:adpSubj = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, subjectList);
adpSubj.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); Set only one time in adapter no need for setDropdownviewresource

Comment: problem is you are using spinner id, you have to bind spinner id for Spinner class ex; Spinner spnSubjectIDInfo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

Comment: @EktaDushanj I have already excluded the setDropDownViewResource but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @MinnuKaAnae I'm so sorry for my mistake to forget including that one inside the post.

Comment: @UmarZaii Check my updated answer, it is working, i have tested

Comment: The problem is that the item in the spinner is listed and can be clicked but it doesn't show the value on the spinner field after being clicked

Comment: you have to convert it to String using toString() Check this Toast.makeText(this, parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()+ " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few more searching I realized that I have to set the width size of the spinner to wrap_content as the length of the value doesn't support to display it on the spinner after the item being clicked at.

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spnSubjectIDInfo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
     AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() { 
@Override 
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this, subjectList.get(position).toString() " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    } 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you.

```
public class SpinnerTest extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList<String> subjectList;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adpSubj;
private Spinner spinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_spinner_test);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    spinner= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnSubjectIDInfo);

    subjectList = new ArrayList<String>();
    subjectList .add("John");
    subjectList .add("Maxi");
    subjectList .add("Jeni");

    adpSubj = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, subjectList);
    adpSubj.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adpSubj);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), spinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for not mentioning this early but actually the onItemSelected() is not called at all. I have tested it with System.out.println()

Comment: Now the toast have shown, but the value on the spinner doesn't showed up after being clicked on the item inside it.

Comment: you have to convert it to String using toString() Check this Toast.makeText(this, parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()+ " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the wrong context to Toast instance:

If your code is in Activity then replace `this` by `YourActivity.this` or if it's in Fragment then use `getActivity()` or use Application context `getApplicationContext()`. Because currently, `this` is representing Spinner's onItemSelected listener context.

**Do :**

```
Toast.makeText(/*Your activity/application context*/, parent.getItemAtPosition(position)+ " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**instead of:**

```
Toast.makeText(this, parent.getItemAtPosition(position)+ " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: I'm sorry for not mentioning this early but actually the onItemSelected() is not called at all. I have tested it with System.out.println(). Toast has no problem at all atm.

Answer (score 1):

Change the "this" to "ActvityName.this" or use "getApplicationContext()" in the Toast, you are passing anonymous class context in the toast.

Like below:

```
spnSubjectIDInfo.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this,parent.getItemAtPosition(position)+ " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry for not mentioning this early but actually the onItemSelected() is not called at all. I have tested it with System.out.println()

Answer (score 1):

in Spinner setOnItemSelectedListener methord not work. if you want to get selected value show in toast use this line

```
String Text = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
Toast.makeText(this,Text,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

it will return the selected value and will be displayed on Toast.